# How to Pass parameters to Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two input control and and one Html.ActionLink control on my page. How do i pass the value of these input control as parameter to Controller Action.

```
<input id="txtName" value="MyName" type="Text"/>
<input id="txtAge" value="20" type="Text"/>

<%: Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddName", "EditProfile", new{ --- What to Pass--}, new { @Class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "AddCarrierDialog", data_dialog_title = "Add Carrier" })%>
```

My Controller take two parameter to show detail

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddName(string Name, int Age)
 {
            return PartialView("ShowData");
 }
```

I am not able to pass txtName and TxtAge values to controller Action. Can Anyone help me out. 
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

You will need javascript in order to achieve that. A better approach would be to use an html `<form>` instead of an action link as it will automatically send the values that the user entered in the input fields to the server:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddName", "EditProfile", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "AddCarrierDialog", data_dialog_title = "Add Carrier" })) { %>
    <input id="txtName" value="MyName" type="text" />
    <input id="txtAge" value="20" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
<% } %>
```